# What is a responsive site, why use them, and how to develop them?

Tags: responsive

What is a responsive web site? and Why use a responsive web site? and How to develop such a web site?

Are there any frameworks available to develop a responsive web site?

Comment: Too broad. I suggest looking up on Ethan Marcotte and Jeremy Keith. You need to buy into the philosophy first. They are like the fathers of RWD

Comment: A simple google search will yield tonnes of articles on each of your questions!

Comment: Instead of asking here, you should search it on Google, where you will find all the answers.

Comment: I don't know how this survived when  it was asked a year ago, but this was firmly off-topic then, as it is now. Readers are keen to encourage all question authors to research their questions before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Responsive website**: A website that is flexible in design for all size of devices like mobile, tablet, laptop, large screen computers.

**Why responsive**: to provide good and user friendly interface across multiple platforms (mobile, tablet, laptop, large screen computers).

**How to develop responsive website:** You can create responsive website using a media query, for different size of devices:

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

You have to write css for different media query sizes.

**Frontend CSS Frameworks** : There are lots of framework available for making responsive websites

- Bootstrap 4 : http://getbootstrap.com/
- Materialize : https://materializecss.com/
- Semantic  UI : https://semantic-ui.com/

There are more, but for beginners, Bootstrap is the best one to learn.

Answer (score 1):

> Since we don't have consistent screen sizes so to build a website
>   which will scale according to every screen is the responsive nature.
>   We want to build a website which can fit any screen without jittering
>   or breaking. It should not only work on different desktop screen but
>   also on mobile browsers.

There are many ways by which you can make your website responsive

1. Bootstrap: you can use [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), its easy and you will 
   be able to grasp it in matters on hours
2. [RWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) (responsive web designs)
3. media queries

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Web Design is a concept where you make the page responsive to the width of a browser window. So, as and when you keep resizing the browser you will see the page changing dynamically and giving the user the optimum page view in different “Browser” widths.

It is built using the following concepts to provide this flexibility.

- **Media Queries** – CSS Style rules decide what layout to load based on the the browser width and resolution
- **Fluid Images and grids** – Giving the size of images and page elements in relative units like percentages instead of absolute units like pixels

As people have already mentioned there are so many different frameworks available for designing responsive websites like Bootstrap, Skeleton, Simple, Cascade, Sencha Touch, Materialize and so on. You have a lot of options.